# How to condense a data frame into a matrix of "Yes" or "No" values in R?

Tags: r

Sorry if the title wasn't very self-explanatory.  I have a data frame, df:

```
df <- structure(list(df = c("cat", "dog", "cat", "fish", 
"dog", "cat")), row.names = c("house1a", "house1b", 
"house2a", "house2b", "house3", "house4"
), class = "data.frame")

> df
          df
house1a  cat
house1b  dog
house2a  cat
house2b fish
house3   dog
house4   cat
```

I want to be able to have the animal types as rownames, and then have a "Yes" or "No" value if they are present in each household.  Note that there are multiple rows per household - eg. house1a and house1b are both house1.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
df_new <- structure(list(
house1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No"), 
house2 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), 
house3 = c("No", "Yes", "No"), 
house4 = c("Yes", "No", "No")), 
row.names = c("cat", "dog", 
"fish"), class = "data.frame")

> df_new
     house1 house2 house3 house4
cat     Yes    Yes     No    Yes
dog     Yes     No    Yes     No
fish     No    Yes     No     No
```

What is the best way to create this in R?

Comment: Try: `table(df$df, substring(rownames(df), 1, 6))`

Comment: Thank you!  If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
table(df$df, substring(rownames(df), 1, 6))
#      house1 house2 house3 house4
# cat       1      1      0      1
# dog       1      0      1      0
# fish      0      1      0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
df$house <- row.names(df)
res <- dplyr::group_by(df, house) 
res <- dplyr::summarise(res, containscat = "cat" %in% df, containsdog = "dog" %in% df)
> res
# A tibble: 6 x 3
house   containscat containsdog
<chr>   <lgl>       <lgl>      
  1 house1a TRUE        FALSE      
2 house1b FALSE       TRUE       
3 house2a TRUE        FALSE      
4 house2b FALSE       FALSE      
5 house3  FALSE       TRUE       
6 house4  TRUE        FALSE
```

Comment: Imagine 100 different animals. Plus there are only 4 houses.